# Is a `django model` type abstraction available for c++?

Tags: c++, database, django, orm, django-models

In Django (which uses python), you can very easily create 'models' that allow you to abstract away all of the SQL and simply use objects to retrieve/store information from a database.

Can anyone point me to c++ library that allows me to do the same thing? Currently we're using a postgres backend and interfacing to it with libpqxx. We're create our own object oriented data models but have to essentially copy/paste sql code over and over and then make modifications to it for each 'model'. God help us if we have to move to a different backend as most of this code would need to be tweaked (it currently isn't abstracted in a way to just create a different backend piece).

Does a library exist that will allow me to connect to different types of backend databases and abstract away the need to write any SQL to define and use our database models?

Comment: @Marcin Any chance you can mention one that you've used or your experiences?  Any chance you have one that will mimic what's possible with Django?

Comment: I've never used one in C++. I only saw this question because of the django tag. That said, you should now be able to google this relatively easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141/good-orm-for-c-solutions) was closed, it has numerous answers relevant to your question included in it.

Comment: I recommend that everyone vote to reopen that question. I have.

Comment: I don't have reopen voting rights myself, but I did upvote the question.

Comment: You can help by voting up my comment to that effect on the linked question, thus making it more visible.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to take a look at quince: http://www.quince-lib.com

It isn't exactly django, but it does save you writing sql by hand. As for different databases, quince needs a corresponding backend library of its own for each such database. Currently it has backend libraries for PostgreSQL and sqlite.

(Full disclosure: I wrote it.)